# Problema de DomPDF en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer, dompdf

tengo una pagina de laravel y en ella un boton que me genera un pdf utilizando DomPdf, el problema es que al presionarlo no encuentra el modulo, al presionar el boton me sale este error:

**(1/1) ErrorException
Class 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade' not found**

al desinstalar el paquete no tuve ningun problema pero al instalarlo de nuevo con:

**composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf**

me sale el siguiente error:
[image: problema al instalar DomPDF]

ALguien tendra idea del como solucionarlo???

Comment: Prueba eliminando el archivo `composer.lock` y volviendo a correr `composer install`. Si no lo resuelves así, comparte el contenido de `composer.json` en la pregunta